# Visual Studio 2013 Server Explorer custom data provider: MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to add MongoDB as a custom data provider in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate?

*Server Explorer / Connect to Database*

[image]

I have installed the latest MongoDB C# driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two APIs to be found on the network, both of them implements the ODBC standard:

- One NYU Master's Degree (summer) project, which is compatible with the C++ driver;
- Another, which is provided by Simba Technologies and [available for a trial run](https://www.simba.com/connectors/mongodb-odbc).

After downloading and installing the connector, one must perform a setup with the provided administrator tool, as shown in the following picture.

[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator]

After testing the connection in the *ODBC Data Source Administrator*, one should head over to the Visual Studio's interface, where the Database Connection setup is. One must choose the *.NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC* as a data provider, and the Simba connector will be available, as the following picture shows:

[image]

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

Another ODBC driver was recently released that can be used here.  It has a unique feature in that it exposes the nested MongoDB data model as a set of relational tables.  As a result, the interaction with "relationally" minded apps like Visual Studio will be drastically improved:

http://www.progress.com/products/datadirect-connect/odbc-drivers/data-sources/mongodb

Comment: Very nice alternative!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the references to the MongoDB driver to your project.
You can do this by right clicking on your project in the solution explorer.
And then click Add Reference. Then you can locate the dlls from the MongoDB Driver.
After that you can use them in code.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx
http://www.drdobbs.com/database/mongodb-with-c/240151668?pgno=2

Comment: When I try to add the `.dll`s, IDE says that they have been already added as a reference. I can `use` them in code, but I would like to add a MongoDB as a server in *Server Explorer*.

Comment: I dont think that is possible to do. Atleast after a little research i didnt find anything on adding in the server explorer. I'm sorry.

Comment: I've found a solution.